# Understanding why specific edit was rejected as adressing the author

Tags: discussion, specific-edit

## Minor Prologue

When strolling around SO I recently came across a nice proof for a `math` question. Once I noticed a gap in the reasoning, I properly wrote a comment to notify the author.

Then I thought to myself: “Why place the burden of editing this in on the author?” Thus I edited the answer myself, closing the gap:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13666096

## My Problem

Since this edit was rejected, the author just wrote his own version of this edit (only afterwards noticing mine) and the answer is fine now. That is not my problem.

From reading a myriad of other “Why was my edit rejected?” questions here on meta, I reached the conclusion that I should have been more specific in my edit message when suggesting such a significant edit. This is understandable and I will try to do so in the future. That is not my problem either.

However, the edit was rejected as trying to address the author. Which, in my opinion, could be easily seen as not being the case. That *is* my problem.

## Many Questions

Could this actually be mistaken as addressing the author?

- If so, please help seeing me, how.
- If not, why was this reason chosen?

  - Is there simply no better fit?
  - Am I unaware of some other meaning of this reason which makes it actually a good fit?

## Maybe Duplicates

The answer to these questions probably coincides with or at least closely resembles that of a similar question. However, the search for this particular answer is like the one for the needle in the haystack *if you needed to think a minute or two about every blade of hay to conclude it is indeed not a needle*.

Suggestions to better navigate meta would be very welcome. Usually, searching is something I'm reasonably good at but on meta I fail horribly.

Comment: What if your edit was logically incorrect and turned the answer into nonsense. It's not you who would get the downvotes for that it's the original author of the answer. So if you see something wrong with an answer either comment on that answer or write your own answer.

Comment: As I wrote above, I did comment, too. And as I wrote above, I'm not here to discuss whether this should have been rejected. (But if you want, we can do that, as well.) I do not have a problem with the rejection but with the *stated reason*.

Comment: The reasons are boilerplate, there's a few to choose from. The reason chosen broadly says you should tell the author this (probably via a comment) rather than editing the question.

Comment: Then, imho, the wording is poor. If, instead of “intended to address” something along the lines of “should be brought to the attention” is / can be meant, it should be reflected in the message. (Or, a least, it should come with a nice little link, explaining in more detail the possible meanings of this option.)